# R binary metrics by percentile

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels, r-parsnip

Is there a tidyverse/tidymodels (or base R) way to compute binary classification metrics by adjusting the threshold for a specific positive percentile?

The tidymodels guide suggests preparing a prediction probabilities dataframe which produces positive probabilities (`.pred_1`) and also includes the actual classes `Day90`:

```
> rf_fit %>% predict(test, type="prob") %>% bind_cols(test %>% select(Day90))
# A tibble: 31,586 × 3
   .pred_1 .pred_0 Day90
     <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>
 1  0.296    0.704 0    
 2  0.296    0.704 0    
 3  0.136    0.864 0    
 4  0.0690   0.931 0    
 5  0.0882   0.912 0    
 6  0.0948   0.905 0    
 7  0.157    0.843 0    
 8  0.0572   0.943 0    
 9  0.108    0.892 0    
10  0.0466   0.953 0    
# ℹ 31,576 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

`type="quantile"` is promising but not available for parsnip's `rand_forest()`.

Ideally there is a function that takes a positive percentile, say 20%, and finds a probability threshold `k` that results in about 20% predicted positive. I could sort the probabilities and perform a linear or binary search on `k`, but I'm sure this is already implemented in a more robust way. `dplyr::percent_rank()` also seems promising.

Comment: what do you mean by *20% predicted positive*?

Comment: I mean, given a binary probability threshold, the resulting predictions have about 20% as predicted positive.

Comment: That is my question. What is predicted positive? Is it False positives? True positives? what does it mean

Comment: The predicted class is 1. It doesn't consider the actual class.

Comment: use `uniroot(\(thresh)mean(rf_fit$.pred_1>thresh) - 0.2, c(0.5, 1))` and the root should be the threshold

Comment: or try `quantile(rf_fit$.pred_1, 0.8)`

Comment: Both of those should yield a fairly good threshold to `k`

Comment: @Onyambu looking at this question again, can you post quantile as an answer? I think it's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `quantile` function:

```
quantile(rf_fit$.pred_1, 0.8)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty unclear but I'm guessing that you mean a gain curve:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(probably)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'probably'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.factor, as.ordered

tidymodels_prefer()
options(pillar.advice = FALSE, pillar.min_title_chars = Inf)

head(segment_logistic)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   .pred_poor .pred_good Class
#>        <dbl>      <dbl> <fct>
#> 1      0.986    0.0142  poor 
#> 2      0.897    0.103   poor 
#> 3      0.118    0.882   good 
#> 4      0.102    0.898   good 
#> 5      0.991    0.00914 poor 
#> 6      0.633    0.367   good

segment_logistic %>% 
  gain_curve(Class, .pred_good) %>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think it's close. My use case is given a predicted positive proportion, find a threshold that I can apply to classify and then compute binary metrics. I think `quantile` given by @Onyambu is the simplest way to achieve this.